# Can't talk to Tullius about Season Unending

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can get Ulfric to talk and agree to join in the peace treaty but Tullius will NOT even give me the option.

I have NOT joined either side in the civil war.  However, I have completed the starting quest for both sides; yet, I still have not taken the oath for either side.

What can I do to help fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by going into the console and resetting the quest

```
resetquest CW01A
```

After that I was able to tell Tullius about the peace talks.

Make sure you keep a save from before doing this as messing with quests in the console can break things.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually join a side in order to do this quest. Finish one of the two "join faction" quests to the point where the other one fails and you swear the oath. Then continue seasons unending.

I strongly recommend you don't though, it is absolutely atrocious and made me rage quit skyrim for a year or so. When I returned to skyrim I avoided this quest by joining a side and winning. You are also missing out on a bunch of achievements and a lot of interesting missions by not doing the civil war properly.

If you do choose to proceed with this quest, consult this section
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Season_Unending#Notes
which lists the various quests and achievements that can be broken by this quest, and how to avoid these problems.

Comment: Your link contradicts your first paragraph. You need to talk to both Ulfric and Tullius about Helgen, but you do _not_ need to pick a side.

Comment: I double checked and no contradiction
> "If you have not yet joined either the Imperial Legion or the Stormcloaks, and you have not talked to Ulfric and/or Tullius since Helgen, you will be forced to first talk to them about Helgen, at which point they will suggest that you join their side of the conflict. To proceed, simply finish and exit the first dialogue, then start a new discussion, at which point the option will appear."

It clearly states you need to both join a side AND talk to ulfric or tullius

Comment: "They will suggest you join their side," but it does not say that you must actually do so. It says to just exit out of the dialog and talk to them again.

Comment: That same UESP page talks about what happens in the quest if you are neutral -- how can you be neutral if you've picked a side? (And since I've done this quest as neutral/unaffiliated, i can vouch for the accuracy of this.)

Comment: The UESP page may not state that you have to join a side, but from my own experience Tullius wouldn't give me any speech options other than to take the oath or refuse.  I'm at the final stage of both "Joining the Legion" and "Joining the Stormcloaks", just before taking either oath.  Ulfric let me talk about the truce, but Tullius wouldn't.  I ended up using `resetquest CW01A` as suggested by smithkm, and after that I could talk to Tullius about the truce.

Answer (score 1):

You must be during the quest when you have to kill all the bandits at a fort in order to join the Legion. When you talk to the General without killing the bandits, he says:

> - I believe the Legate has gave you a contract, and must be fulfilled. Dissmissed.

You need to kill all the bandits at the fort and then talk to the Legate and the General.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this bug, but what I know is that last time I did the main quest (without bugs at the truce) and then tried to do the civil war, I had to take a fort which had already switched sides thanks to the peace treaties. Stormcloaks on the ground and Stormcloaks on the walls looking at each other.

Answer (score 0):

For having talked Tullius into it:

`SetStage MQ302 20`

for Ulfric:

`SetStage MQ302 30`

Use the console (<kbd>~</kbd>)